# Running programs on a daily task / cron job?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cron, scheduled-tasks, data-import

What exactly is involved when you schedule a task or chron job? I have an application that my manager wants to run daily at a certain time, the application relies on user input but its designed to save user preferences and load those in as well, as soon as the user clicks a button it will perform the task. How do I go about forcing this to happen daily, assuming all data entered is valid. This is in MVC / ASP.NET so it would be on windows. But if someone can explain how it works with cron jobs in linux I can figure it out from there as well. Do i need to write a script that calls my mvc code? or any suggestions?

Comment: make Windows Service for that particular task and automate it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample windows service that run every day on given set of time, i think this will help you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DemoWinService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        System.Timers.Timer _timer;
        List<TimeSpan> timeToRun = new List<TimeSpan>();
        public void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            string timeToRunStr = "19:01;19:02;19:00"; //Time interval on which task will run
            var timeStrArray = timeToRunStr.Split(';');
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            foreach (var strTime in timeStrArray)
            {
                timeToRun.Add(TimeSpan.ParseExact(strTime, "g", provider));
            }
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60 * 100 * 1000);
            _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            ResetTimer();
        }


        void ResetTimer()
        {
            TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
            TimeSpan? nextRunTime = null;
            foreach (TimeSpan runTime in timeToRun)
            {

                if (currentTime < runTime)
                {
                    nextRunTime = runTime;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!nextRunTime.HasValue)
            {
                nextRunTime = timeToRun[0].Add(new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0));
            }
            _timer.Interval = (nextRunTime.Value - currentTime).TotalMilliseconds;
            _timer.Enabled = true;

        }

        private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Enabled = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello at " + DateTime.Now.ToString()); //You can perform your task here
            ResetTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi could you explain what this service does? I get that its for scheduling tasks (thank you) but im confused about some of the numbers used? such as             string timeToRunStr = "19:01;19:02;19:00";

Comment: i think you have to read about Windows services , goto this ref http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/naresh.avari/develop-and-install-a-windows-service-in-C-Sharp/